# Question about use of "do" in wh questions

Tags: grammar

What  you usually call a president who is not going to be in power after new election ?

Or

What  do you usually call a president who is not going to be in power after new election ?

My perception: here because the answer is not direct object, first one is correct.

Comment: A quick tip: To make a question, you invert only the main clause. Sorry, I don't have enough time to write a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

*DO-*support is obligatory whenever the term for which *WH-*word stands is **not the subject** of the clause and no other auxiliary is employed.

In this case, although *what* is not a direct object  it **does** act as a complement of the verb *call*. Consider the answer:

> **You call him a *lame duck***.
>   [<sub>SUBJ</sub>**You**] [<sub>VERB</sub>**call**] [<sub>COMP 1</sub> **him**] [<sub>COMP 2</sub>**a lame duck**].

There is no other auxiliary in the verb; consequently, you must call in *DO-*support to form a question:

> What ***do*** you call ... ?